# error trying connect the application to server

Tags: react-native, routes, frontend, expo, backend

problem to connect the application to the backend.
I use React Native with EXPO
The error occurs on a login screen when trying to validate a user on a DB in the sql-server

I believe the error is in this: async function sendForm () {
let response = await fetch ('http://myip:3000/login'

however, I don't know what could be wrong ... suddenly some Node module is missing.

1 - already redone the project

2 - deleted node_modules and yarn install to remake

3 - already test the Controller.js routes and they are working.

4 - images: https://ibb.co/B354qky https://ibb.co/ZRjKRnn https://ibb.co/pyDyM70

THIS IS THE ERROR:
[Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<']
at [native code]:null in parse
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guardat node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

Comment: code is not clear can you please paste your code ?

Comment: Welcome and hello to SO, please add your code instead of the screenshots and format the error output.